# Change parent pseudo element based on child attribute with :has using SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

Im trying to change an elements pseudo content based on whether or not its child has a certain attribute.

For example, I want to display different font awesome icons based on whether  or not a bootstrap collapsable div has the attribute `aria-expanded="true"`.

**HTML**

```
   <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h5 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#month1">01/01/2001 - 01/02/2001</a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="month1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    test
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How would I change the h5 pseudo content based on if the child `a` tag has a certain attribute?

I would have thought something like this would work

```
.panel-heading {
  h5:has(> a[aria-expanded="true"]){
    &::after {
      content: "\f055";
      font-family: FontAwesome; 
      float:right; 
    }   
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything. Using anything with the `:has` selector in my SASS code doesn't seem to work.

For example, something simple like

```
 h5:has(a){
    &::after {
      content: "\f055";
      font-family: FontAwesome; 
      float:right; 
    }   
  }
}
```

doesn't even work.

What is the correct way to use `:has` in sass?

Comment: what version of fontAwesome do you use?

Comment: Its not an issue with fontAwesome, the content and font awesome font are working fine, its an issue with the selector.

Comment: I want to know to better answer

Comment: `:has` is a css experimental attribute. Not yet supported. You cannot select a parent depending on a child. Only the other way around ( with CSS )

Comment: @S_R See here working code:https://jsfiddle.net/21huwjr7/6/

Comment: @לבנימלכה The OP was asking to add `:after` styles on the `h5` not on the `a`.

Comment: @לבנימלכה I'm trying to apply the styling to the h5, not the a tag.